# Attempt by security transparent method to access security critical type failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, autofac

I am getting below error in MVC4 application

```
 Attempt by security transparent method  'Autofac.Integration.Mvc.RegistrationExtensions.RegisterControllers(Autofac.Cont    ainerBuilder, System.Reflection.Assembly[])' to access security critical type 'Autofac.Builder.IRegistrationBuilder`3<System.Object,Autofac.Features.Scanning.ScanningActivatorData,Autofac.Builder.DynamicRegistrationStyle>' failed.

 Assembly 'Autofac.Integration.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  
 PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da' is marked with the  
 AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute, and uses the level 2 security 
 transparency model.  Level 2 transparency causes all methods in 
 AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers assemblies to become security transparent by 
 default, which may be the cause of this exception.
```

I tried different solutions given in below links but none of them work for me
[Attempt by security transparent method to access security critical method failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252500/attempt-by-security-transparent-method-to-access-security-critical-method-failed)

[Attempt by security transparent method xxx to access security critical yy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061380/attempt-by-security-transparent-method-xxx-to-access-security-critical-yy) and 
https://forums.asp.net/t/1939805.aspx

Please help

Comment: Did u get a chance to look at this .https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/459

Comment: You need to put more in here, like your NuGet packages.config so we can see what you're referencing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I replaced Autofac 4.0.0 with version Autofac 3.5.0 and Autofac.Integration.Mvc to 3.0.0. This resolved the problem

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty sure this is the version issue. I installed Autofac.WebApi by mistake, the version of Autofac was automatically 3.x.x. Then the issue came. After that I realized I had to use Autofac.WebApi2 instead of Autofac.WebApi. I installed, Autofac version went up to 4.6.2, then booom the issue was solved.

Hope it helps

Comment: This is the correct solution to the problem. I also used WebApi instead of WebApi2